# Minimum number of connections to have all dots at a maximum distance $\delta$

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

If we have some set of $n$ non-colinear dots, and we define a segment as every line joining two dots, the minimum number of segments to assure that all dots are connected with each other without having any dot between them ($\delta=0$) would be $N (0)=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$, as we would have to connect every dot with each one of the other dots.

If we allow to have at most one dot between them ($\delta=1$), then $N(1)=n-1$, as we can draw segments from one dot (which we can call the central dot) to every other dot ($n-1$ segments), and this way every dot would be connected with each other with at most one dot between them (the central dot).

It seems that in fact $N(\delta>1)=N(1)$, I have found no way in which some $N(\delta>1)<n-1$; so I conjecture that $N(\delta\geq1)=n-1$.

How could it be proved (or disproved) such a result? Is it a known theorem, or can be derived from a known one? And I would be interested in some insight (if any) on the implications of this result, that shows a great constraint, because it would imply that we could allow $\delta$ to be as big as $n-2$, and still the minimum number of segments connecting the dots would be $n-1$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to connect $n$ dots in any way takes $n-1$ edges.  As you say, that succeeds for $N(1)$ but increasing the allowable number of dots in between does not decrease it.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Could you please provide some proof of it? It seems straight and simple, but I do not guess how it could be done

Comment: Each edge can connect one more dot to the growing tree.  You start with one dot that is connected (by itself) and have to connect $n-1$ more.